# What project options to use for open source Delphi packages?

Tags: delphi, open-source, delphi-xe2, project-organization

I've written some Delphi code I would like to share on GitHub. All code is contained in runtime and designtime packages as required. There are many Project Options to set for each project. (Output directories, search paths, compilation options, etc.) I've managed to find some default options that work well for my situation but reading other Q&As here it's clear there are multiple [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/812773/395461) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/543949/395461) [working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259673/what-is-the-best-way-to-share-delphi-source-files-among-projects?lq=1).

**What project options should be used to allow the open source packages to easily be incorporated into other projects?**

[image: Delphi Project Options]

Comment: Fro a start all search paths should be relative. And then you should create a version of your demo project where you add your components at runtie. Personally I newer install components in my Delphi before i know for sure that I need them, and non visible components i never install

Comment: Compiler Options: Range and Overflow checking always on. Let the computer work for you catching errors.

Comment: What is the scope of the question? You want to know about all options? Compiler options? Or just path related options?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'd like info on path options and other options you would consider important.

Comment: I think that's too broad. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Any suggestions on how to trim the question down to be more focused?

Comment: You should ask for something specific about a specific problem. Not just trying to pick up tips on anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have this structure

- MyComponent

  - Packages

    - DelphiXE7

      - Package2.dpr
  - source
  - bin

    - Delphi XE7

then set

- **Search Path**

  > ..\..\..\source
- **Unit output directory**

  > ..\..\..\bin\Delphi XE7\$(Platform)\$(Config)

After compilation for **all supported platforms** and both **Release** and **Debug** you will have this structure in the **bin** directory

- MyComponent

  - Packages

    - DelphiXE7

      - Package2.dpr
  - source
  - bin

    - Delphi XE7

      - Android

        - Release
        - Debug
      - Win32

        - Release
        - Debug
      - Win64

        - Release
        - Debug

For installation you have to setup some path inside the IDE.

- **Environment**

  > MYCOMPONENT => [root path to the files]
- **Library**

  Repeat that for all supported platforms

  - **Library Path**

    > $(MYCOMPONENT)\bin\Delphi XE7\$(Platform)\Release
  - **Search Path**

    > $(MYCOMPONENT)\source
  - **Debug-DCU-Path**

    > $(MYCOMPONENT)\bin\Delphi XE7\$(Platform)\Debug

If there are some language related units there is also a place to add (see **Library - translated**)

This ensures, that you have full debug feature (with **Use Debug-DCU** option set) and on release you have no debug code in your application.

---

Just a sidenote on libraries you should not want to install because you only use them in some projects.

Simply use the Optionset combined with a environment variable.

Here my *SuperObject.optionset* (`$(USRLIB)` points to a directory, where I collect all common used source code. And `$(USRLIB)\ext` is the place for all of the external libraries).

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DCC_UnitSearchPath>$(USRLIB)\ext\superobject;$(DCC_UnitSearchPath)</DCC_UnitSearchPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <Borland.Personality>Delphi.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
        <Borland.ProjectType>OptionSet</Borland.ProjectType>
        <BorlandProject>
            <Delphi.Personality/>
        </BorlandProject>
        <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
    </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

To use the superobject library I simply add the optionset to the project (right mouse click on build configuration) and everything is fine.